# Get Jenkins environment variables in execute shell

Tags: shell, jenkins

I was wondering if it is possible to access Jenkins environment variables inside the execute shell in configure build? If so can you show me an example please? I need to combine the environment information with some output of the test to give a full report of a run (not using plugins).

Comment: see the  following links, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables,  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Please check `http://yourjenkins-url/env-vars.html/`. All the environment variable can be used by surrounding with `${}` 
[image]

After successfully built, You can see output like this:

[image]