# Jenkins environment variables are missed

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, environment-variables

I can't find/use Jenkins variables in linux shell on the master server, `env` command doesn't show them at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the environment variables, that are used during the build, are only declared in the context of job execution.

But you can still check their values from the Jenkins's UI. Take a look at the related post here: [Get Jenkins environment variables in execute shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009589/get-jenkins-environment-variables-in-execute-shell#31032618)

So here you can find a list of all env variables: `https://<your-jenkins>/env-vars.html`

And you can check their values by echoing them in the `Execute Shell` section.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that they are declared while the Jenkins installation as an environment variables and I can use them directly in the terminal, didn’t know that they are declared during the build process.