# SVN environment variables not available in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, svn, ant

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009589/get-jenkins-environment-variables-in-execute-shell) solution doesn't work for me :-(

I want to use SVN_REVISION in my Ant build.xml

SVN_REVISION and SVN_URL are listed in /env-vars.html
but if I want to use them in Ant or in the execute shell as above (e.g. echo ${SVN_REVISION}) none of the values are set.

Though the correct revision is displayed when checking out: "At revision 1234"

What is going wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: I once had '//' instead of '/' as path separator in my repository URL. The funny thing is that besides the SVN environment variables everything was working fine.